# Finding manuscripts of Rb. Yerucham

Tags: product-recommendation, internet, manuscripts

I'm looking for manuscripts of the work of Rb. Yeruchaem - both Isur v'heter and Toldot Adam V'chava. Ideally I'd like to see them without having to travel great distances, which means finding them online. I've checked the National Library of Israel already and come up empty. I also searched the [Vatican](http://digi.vatlib.it/) (don't laugh - they have a significant number of Judaic manuscripts scanned and accessible for free). JTS [seems to have](http://primo-tc-na01.hosted.exlibrisgroup.com/primo_library/libweb/action/display.do?ct=display&fn=search&doc=JTS_ALEPH000075808&indx=3&recIds=JTS_ALEPH000075808&recIdxs=2&elementId=2&renderMode=poppedOut&displayMode=full&frbrVersion=&tabs=detailsTab&gathStatTab=true&fromBrowseShelf=true&mulIncFctN=facet_rtype&gathStatTab=true&dscnt=0&callNumberBrowseField=browse_callnumber&mode=Basic&vid=JTS&tabRealType=browseshelf&tab=default_tab&fromBrowseShelf=true&dstmp=1479611632549&fctIncV=archive_manuscripts&rfnGrpCounter=1&frbg=&frbrVersion=&scp.scps=scope%3A%28%22JTS%22%29%2Cscope%3A%28JTS_EAD%29%2Cscope%3A%28JTS_ALEPH%29&rfnIncGrp=1&tb=t&srt=rank&callNumber=ms+r521&vl(freeText0)=%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%97%D7%9D&dum=true) but they don't seem to be accessible online. Anyone know where to find one?

Comment: Try [JNUL](http://www.jnul.huji.ac.il/eng/digibook.html). [This](http://aleph.nli.org.il/F/8QRINSTH2E9C9APBLC3K2PC8AJ2C7ELY35PDBAFEURFFSLCHC9-03916?func=find-acc&acc_sequence=017631219) should take you to an old edition. A DejaVu viewer is necessary to view these. See also [here](http://aleph.nli.org.il/F/8QRINSTH2E9C9APBLC3K2PC8AJ2C7ELY35PDBAFEURFFSLCHC9-00122?func=scan&scan_code=TIT&local_base=NNLALL&scan_start=%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA+%D7%90%D7%93%D7%9D+%D7%95%D7%97%D7%95%D7%94).

Comment: Not a manuscript, but http://hebrewbooks.org/9380 is a printed edition from 1553, which is pretty old.

Comment: The vatican has one: http://digi.vatlib.it/mss/detail/195533

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I don't think this will be the most used answer on this site, I did find the answer so I figured I might as well post it just on the off chance someone else is wondering the same thing.

**Toldot Adam V'Chava**

According to רבינו ירוחם השלם, the new critical edition of all his works, there are four main manuscripts for Toldot Adam V'Chava:

- JTS RAB 669 [[catalog link](http://primo-tc-na01.hosted.exlibrisgroup.com/primo_library/libweb/action/search.do?fn=search&ct=search&initialSearch=true&mode=Basic&tab=default_tab&indx=1&dum=true&srt=rank&vid=JTS&frbg=&tb=t&vl%28freeText0%29=MS+R669&scp.scps=scope%3A%28%22JTS%22%29%2Cscope%3A%28JTS_EAD%29%2Cscope%3A%28JTS_ALEPH%29)] [[NLI digitization](http://web.nli.org.il/sites/NLI/English/digitallibrary/pages/viewer.aspx?&presentorid=MANUSCRIPTS&docid=PNX_MANUSCRIPTS000112732-1)]
- JTS RAB 1150 [[catalog link](http://primo-tc-na01.hosted.exlibrisgroup.com/primo_library/libweb/action/search.do?fn=search&ct=search&initialSearch=true&mode=Basic&tab=default_tab&indx=1&dum=true&srt=rank&vid=JTS&frbg=&tb=t&vl%28freeText0%29=MS+R1150&scp.scps=scope%3A%28%22JTS%22%29%2Cscope%3A%28JTS_EAD%29%2Cscope%3A%28JTS_ALEPH%29)]
- Vatican 499 [[link](http://digi.vatlib.it/mss/detail/195533)]
- St. Petersburg EVR II A313/24

**Isur V'Heter**

According to the newest research, it looks like this book was not authored by Rb. Yerucham (or at least not the same one), and was attributed to him by mistake. (For more on that, see the relevant chapter in [this book](http://www.kotar.co.il/kotarapp/index/Book.aspx?nBookID=99933348) by professor Israel Ta-Shma). For that reason it is not included in the newest critical editions of his work. In any case, Prof Ta-Shma did identify two manuscripts:

- Cambridge Add 561/2 [[NLI info](http://web.nli.org.il/sites/NLIS/en/ManuScript/Pages/Item.aspx?ItemID=PNX_MANUSCRIPTS000138971)]
- [Moskova-Ginzburg 73/2](http://sammlungen.ub.uni-frankfurt.de/mshebr/content/titleinfo/1837657) (online)